# How to make a new pandas DataFrame with percentages of items shared by columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(5, 4)),
columns=list('ABCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   1   1
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   1   1   1
3   1   0   0   1
4   0   1   0   1
```

I would like to find the percentage of overlap of counts of 1s for each column compared with all other column in the DataFrame.

For example column A has 2 shared 1s with column B and contains a total of 3 1s. That would mean an overlap of 66%. B contains 4 1s and has 2 shared 1s with column A. That would mean an overlap of 50%.

As a result I would like to get a new DataFrame which contains percentage values for all column pairs:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   100 50  43  31
B   66  100 91  19
C   38  52  100 65
D   23  29  68  100
```

(Just an example, not containing all the correct values for the first DataFrame)

What is the most straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use matrix multiplication to get the number of 1s which are common in both columns. To normalize, divide by the column sums:

```
df.T.dot(df) / df.sum()
Out: 
          A     B    C     D
A  1.000000  0.50  1.0  0.75
B  0.666667  1.00  1.0  0.75
C  0.666667  0.50  1.0  0.50
D  1.000000  0.75  1.0  1.00
```